# Setup FTP file upload and download services in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

We have roughly 250 customers using our existing on-premises FTP service to upload and download large graphic files.
I would like to move this service to AWS. I want to keep the costs to a minimum at the same time setup security to maintain customer privacy.
I would like to use S3? Customer will be using S3 client instead of FTP client.
The solution needs to be scalable.

Do I use a single S3 bucket or one bucket per customer with a Bucket policy that permits access only to that one customer?

Should I use Requester Pays? What is requester pays?

Comment: Do you think your customers are prepared to use an S3 client?  Mine aren't. (S)FTP is something of an embedded, de facto standard for transfers.  How large are the files?  What is your motivation for requester pays?  Each client in such a scenario would need their own AWS account, because the "requester" is an AWS account other than your own, and this feature requires specific support for the modified API request in the client code.

Comment: Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23946418/1695906) as an easier option.  I have never gotten around to writing the FTP/S3 bridge I had been contemplating designing, because this solution just works.

Answer (score 0):

**Requester pays**
Requester pays is , when a particular application from an amazon account makes a "api call" to the particular bucket then , they are charged. In simple terms who ever makes the request , pays for the charge.

**Amazons Definition** :
In general, bucket owners pay for all Amazon S3 storage and data transfer costs associated with their bucket. A bucket owner, however, can configure a bucket to be a Requester Pays bucket. With Requester Pays buckets, the requester instead of the bucket owner pays the cost of the request and the data download from the bucket. The bucket owner always pays the cost of storing data.

**Important**
If you enable Requester Pays on a bucket, anonymous access to that bucket is not allowed.

**Regarding the s3 bucket per customer** , you may allocate each bucket to each customer , and you allocate tags per customer as the billing can be consolidated, you have a "soft limit" of 100 buckets per account , which means that you can increase them when ever you want.