# Connecting to Cloud Storage Bucket via FTP

Tags: amazon-s3, ftp, google-cloud-storage

I have a specific need to connect to a cloud storage bucket (Amazon or Google) via FTP.

So I would have multiple buckets with different FTP Accounts linking to each one.

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: There's a workaround that can emulate this reasonably well, compatible with the far-end being strictly unaware of S3 and speaking ftp (or sftp) it involves [running s3fs on an FTP server in EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23946418/1695906).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Neither S3 nor any of its popular clones support FTP access, in large part because the operations exposed to FTP do not map well to S3. (For instance, it is impossible to atomically rename a 'directory' in S3, and FTP does not expose any file metadata beyond UNIX permissions.)

However, a number of desktop FTP clients can also work with S3 (and S3-compatible) storage. One such client is [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it's to link the files to other services that need to use FTP. I appreciate the thorough input though.