# File upload to ec2 then s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftps, proftpd

I have setup an FTPS server with PROFTPD on ec2 and mounted it on s3. I want to upload and download files using java that will first pass ec2 to have an FTPS transfer before it goes to S3. How and what's the best way to do it?

****Client > EC2 > S3 (upload a file to my server (EC2 running Centos 7) then the server uploads the file to S3)****

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23946418/1695906)?

Comment: No, I have already setup my S3 bucket to have an FTPS access using EC2 instance in PROFTPD. My S3 and EC2 is already connected. What I want right now is to know how to upload files from my computer going to s3 that will pass thru ec2 and to download it vice versa.

Comment: If you already have that set up, then that's what happens with this configuration -- the files pass through the EC2 instance on the way to/from S3... so what are you asking?  You may need to describe it differently or in more detail.

Comment: I need a code that will upload/download files with that kind of setup but I don't know how its done. I've tried a code but it doesn't pass ec2 it goes straight to s3