# Python, aws s3 - data with images bulk importing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, import, bulk-import

I am new here at stackoverflow.

I have a question regarding a process of bulk importing of data.

Scenario:
We have XYZ system that have a feature to bulk import data, but we are having trouble on how we can do the bulk import of images to aws S3 via SFTP. Take note that these images are related to data that have been imported via bulk import.

Hoping to hear back from anyone that is knowledgeable on this regard. Thanks.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

S3 does not have native SFTP support.

You can upload to S3 using the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (the [s3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) option may be useful), write your own uploader using the S3 APIs, or find a 3rd-party solution.

If you absolutely must have SFTP, then see another Stack Overflow post: [FTP/SFTP access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939179/ftp-sftp-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket).

Comment: Thanks @jarmod for the info, will definitely look into your suggestions.