# How can I FTP(SSL) into a private AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS S3 Bucket holding a development website.  I would like to FTP(SSL) into the S3 Bucket, and also be able to create username and password credentials for others.  Is this possible, and how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, SFTP is not possible with native S3 services/tools. You might be able to find some third-party FTP projects that can proxy the interface to S3.

Comment: And, that explains why I was not able to find any information on how to do this.  What is the point of using an S3 bucket, and code deploy, if you are not allowed to update the S3 bucket in an easy manner?  Meh, Ill have to switch to a git repo.

Comment: There are plenty of simple options for uploading/downloading S3 objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTP/SFTP access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939179/ftp-sftp-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before giving up on S3 remember that sometimes frustration with a new product or technology comes from lack of knowledge and experience. The Amazon Cloud platform has some amazing services to work with.

FTP is an old technology that is not as popular today. The new style is using REST interfaces. S3 supports REST. Also you can easily copy files to / from S3 using command line tools. Look into the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI). Link below.

If your goal is to use S3 as your source repository look into AWS CodeCommit. Very similar to GIT. There is also CodePipeline, CodeBuild and CodeDeploy. Combine these tools with other Amazon services such as CloudFormation and you have real developer power.

[AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

[AWS Code Services](https://aws.amazon.com/products/developer-tools/)

[AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  Looks like what I wanted was the Code Commit, and Code Pipeline to target it. with Code Deploy!

Comment: Your are welcome Mike. Also these tools are easy to work with and you will find support for them easy to find.