# Mount an S3 bucket to SFTP server with file processing step in the middle?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Possibly an unusual idea. I have an S3 bucket with thousands of XML files on it.

I want to serve that bucket contents from a SFTP server (not sure how yet, possibly: [FTP/SFTP access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939179/ftp-sftp-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket))

The catch is that I need to edit the XML files slightly which I have a python script to do so. I want to serve those edited versions of the files from the SFTP, with the source of their contents being the S3 bucket.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: My fallback plan is to download everything onto a new s3 bucket then process and save it again. But Id like to keep one source of truth for those files if possible.

Comment: check out `boto3` module for python for AWS communications..https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/