# Bash script for FTP file transfer from Raspberry Pi to Amazon S3

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, ftp, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to transfer .bin files from my Raspberry Pi 2 to an Amazon S3 server using a bash script "connect_ftp_amazon" as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='XX.XXX.XXX.XXX'
USER='my_user'
PASSWD='my_password'
DIR='/s3_folder'
LOCALPATH='/raspberrypi_folder'

ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $DIR
lcd $LOCALPATH
mput *.bin
quit
exit;
EOF
```

However, when I try to execute it in the terminal window with

```
chmod a+x connect_ftp_amazon
sudo ./connect_ftp_amazon
```

I got

```
ftp: connect: Connection timed out
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Local directory now /home/pi/raspberrypi_folder
Not connected.
```

I guess I'm passing my host and/or user parameters in the wrong format, as it works fine with a Linux server. Could somebody help me to identify what is wrong with my settings?

Comment: Do I have to install `aws cli` for this and follow the instructions explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/es/getting-started/tutorials/backup-to-s3-cli/?nc1=h_ls) or just replace `ftp` with `aws s3` in my bash script above?

Comment: Well, that depends on whether you already have `aws` installed or not. You probably don't.

Comment: The technical error here is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect to Amazon S3 with FTP. You have to use S3 protocol.

Use `aws s3` or `s3cmd` commands.

See [Uploading files to S3 account from Linux command line](https://superuser.com/q/279986/213663).

---

Though you can mount S3 bucket to a (Linux) server and setup FTP/SFTP server there. See [FTP/SFTP access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23939179/850848#32378176).