# Create Amazon S3 target and load data from Oracle sources using Informatica powercenter

Tags: amazon-s3, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I need information about how to load data to S3 from Oracle with informatica powercenter 10.2, I start creating mapping but I don't know how to create a target file for amazon S3 and configure the connection to S3 buckets.

I found that I should create amazon S3 data objects in developer tools which need powerexchange Amazon S3.

I worked in another requirement in order to load data into Redshift but here we used ODBC connection.

There is anyone who can tell me more structured details about how to create target for S3 and configure connection and the file size?

Comment: what is your target ? File or databases? If its a file - dont need anything you need to FTP access that location. If its redshift/any RDBMS, i think you can use ODBC drivers from progress. Probably you dont need powerexchange because this is an extra costly tool you can avoid using.

Comment: Thank you @KoushikRoy for your reply, yes my target will be a csv file, have you any reference on how configure ftp connexion between informatica and aws s3 ?

Comment: You need to generate the file in informatica locally and then FTP/SFTP to AWS S3. I think this is something you can use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939179/ftp-sftp-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket You can also use managed SFTP service as per this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-amazon-s3/